# New to C++, Playing with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, comments, codeblocks

Using Code::Blocks IDE for Mac in my C++ class, I'm spending some time trying to clean up my first lab with comments and the like, and the syntax highlighting alerted me to something I can't seem to find documentation over online.

```
    /**
      Author: Name
      Lab1
      Purpose: simulate a calculator with informative menu
    */
```

has a different highlighting color than simply

```
    /*
      What I thought
      a normal multiline comment
      was...
    */
```

and even different still from

```
    // Models a basic calculator with looping menu until sentinel or invalid operator is given
```

I'm curious as to what the purpose/function is to the first code snippet. In Java, this is a docstring. Does it serve the same purpose in C++? If not, what is it, and how is it conventionally used?

Comment: Tools like Doxygen can generate chm documentation through header files, provided a mandated commenting syntax is observed in header files. Such chm files are usually provided as interface documentation.

Comment: C++ itself does not have any such feature, but code blocks might have added support for popular code documentation software like Doxygen

Comment: Thanks @KarthikT for the explanation. If either of you would like an accept or upvote, feel free to answer and I'll close out the question.

Comment: @AlokSave: I have never once generated a chm file with Doxygen, and I'm not sure you could even view one on a Mac. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious: Actually, It is rather easy to generate a chm file with doxygen once you get the default settings in place.I was not aware of limitations of Mac with chm but apparently it [can be done](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chm-view/id449814591?mt=12) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a comment that [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) will recognize as documentation. Doxygen is modeled after Javadoc. And it's rather popular, so it's not surprising that Code::Blocks recognizes it. Doxygen can generate output in a wide variety of formats, including straight HTML that can be viewed with a web browser.

I don't know why it decided that the 2nd and 3rd examples should be a different color. Maybe because one is a block comment and another is 'until the end of line' comment. But that seems like a somewhat trivial distinction to me.

Comment: @AlokSave really deserves the credit for this. If I could assign it to him, I would.